# Delete sitemap from new Google Webmaster Console

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I need to delete in the Google Webmaster Console an old sitemap we don't use anymore and it's generating 404 errors.

My problem is in the new Google Webmaster Console I can't find the option to accomplish the delete (like in the older one). And there is no way to go back to the older Google Webmaster Console.

The official documentation was not updated either -> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669?hl=en

Here's a screenshot of the new webmaster console :
[image: Google Webmaster Console]

**UPDATE Oct. 4, 2018,**
Google added a link to go back to the previous version of Webmaster Console. So I did it and could delete the sitemap. Still not found a way to delete it in the new console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They updated things since this question was asked. By clicking on the sitemap you want to remove, then click on the three dots in the upper right and select "Remove Sitemap."

[image]

Comment: That's it! They finally added the functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to old version, then you can delete sitemaps.

Still couldn't find ways to delete sitemap in new version.

Comment: that was a good workaround, now it's possible, see the accepted answer